# reading linked list from txt file

Tags: c, file, linked-list

Ok so I have been told that to read my lists from file I have somehow to separate data in file I have been recomended to use strtok, It seems I'm reading correct data but how do I pass those to my add AddClient function?

Data in file looks like this:

```
Client: Adrian Kulesza
Item: przedmiot cos 123.000000 cosu 1234.000000 1 2 3

Client: Bartosz Siemienczuk
```

Header:

```
    struct date
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        struct date* next;
    };
    struct item
    {
        char item_name[30];
        char item_state[30];
        float item_price;
        char item_status[30];
        float item_price_if_not;
        struct date *issue_date;
        struct item *next;
    };
    struct client
    {
        char client_name[30];
        char client_last_name[30];
        struct item *item_data;
        struct client *next;
    };
```

Code:

```
void ReadList(struct client *head)
{
  int i=0,b=0;
  char line[126];
  FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    puts("Can't open the file");
    return 1;
  }
  while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
  {
    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    if( strcmp(token,"Client:") == 0)
    {
      while (token != NULL)
      {
        puts(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
    }

    else
      if( strcmp(token,"Item:") == 0)
      {
        while(token != NULL)
        {
          puts(token);
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
      }
    }

void AddClient(struct client **head, char name[30], char last_name[30])
{
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
        strcpy((*head)->client_name,name);
        strcpy((*head)->client_last_name,last_name);
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->item_data = NULL;
    }
    else
{
    struct client *temp;
    temp = (*head);
    //             //
    while(temp->next)
    temp=temp->next;
    //              //
    (temp->next) = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
    strcpy(temp->next->client_name,name);
    strcpy(temp->next->client_last_name,last_name);
    temp->next->next = NULL;
    temp->next->item_data = NULL;
}
}
```

Comment: You write the function but not knowing where to call it? that's weirld...Just after every time you read all the data of one node.

Comment: No I know how to call it with normal data input by user is it possible to add my function into readlist somehow? I dont know exactly how to use strtok and I'm trying here to relink my list from list saved to file

Comment: If you think posting at least the sample data from your input file for the two cases you're accounting for (`Client:` and `Item:`) would be helpful, you'd be right. And your `AddClient` need not special case the head pointer for NULL if it is coded appropriately. As-written, you have `return 1` in a function declared as `void`, missing closing parens for `ReadList`, no sample data, and no `main()` to speak of.

Comment: Well I just showed what I know so far all I want is explanation how could I use those tokens as arguments for my function,or overall based on my ReadList function how could I relink my list,function ReadList was something which I wrote when I got to know that I had no idea how i could distinguish between both lists in file when saved. I'm not that familiar with strtok I just got to know about it 2h ago trying to figure out, and lack of sleep aint helping :/.

Comment: you are missing a final `}` in the last block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that your problem is how to extract first/last name (e.g. Adrian Kulesza)
from line, and passed them into ReadList().

Here is the quick and dirty test code after simplify your problem:

```
int main(void)
{
    char line[126] = "Client: Adrian Kulesza";
    char name[30], last_name[30];

    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    if( strcmp(token,"Client:") == 0)
    {
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(name, token);

      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(last_name, token);
    }   

    printf("%s %s\n", name, last_name);

    return 0;
}
```

You now get name and last_name, pass them into AddClient(),
but you may need error handling and also the item part.